# mouse over operation in python selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to perform mouse over operation in `python` `selenium` binding, but I am getting error while using `ActionChains.perform()`

I have tried this

```
def test_mouse_over():

    driver =webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.get("https://www.flipkart.com/")

    actions = ActionChains(driver)
    val1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[text()="Men"]')
    actions.move_to_element(val1)
    val2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[text()="Shirts"]')
    actions.click(val2)
    actions.perform()
```

I am getting error at last line `actions.perform()`

Comment: You have a syntax error at `actions =Action Chains(driver)`. Please show the error message.

Comment: corrected but still getting same error at perform() function. after comment out last line it properly complied but for performing mouse over operation I have to mention perform() method, might be problem bcz of windows10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

correct solution

```
def test_mouse_over():
    """mouse over operation FLIPKART.COM"""
    driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\Python27\Scripts\chromedriver.exe")  # in chrome this code is working

    # driver = webdriver.Firefox() # in forefox this code is not working

    driver.get("https://www.flipkart.com/")
    driver.implicitly_wait(20)
    driver.maximize_window()

    menu = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[text()='Women']")
    hidden_submenu = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Flats']")

    actions = ActionChains(driver)

    actions.move_to_element(menu).click().perform()

    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Flats']")))
    try:
        actions.click(hidden_submenu).perform()
    except:
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Flats']")))
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to perform both actions in a chain. Try the following code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains as chains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.flipkart.com/")

actions =chains(driver)
val1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//li[a[@title="Men"]]')
actions.move_to_element(val1).perform()
val2 = wait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//a[span[text()="Shirts"]]')))
val2.click()
```

Comment: error         # actions.move_to_element(menu)
    
        val1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//li[a[@title="Men"]]')
>       actions.move_to_element(val1).perform()

TestScripts\test_sample_mouse_over.py:20: 
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _

Comment: Hey :) What is that `actions.move_to_element(menu)` !? There is no such line in my code...as well as in your initial code

Comment: Did you get exception like `Message: POST /session/... did not match a known command` with `Firefox`?